# Razor how to conditionally add title attribute to a tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have this piece of code:

```
    @{ var canUpdatePaymentStatus = !(User.GetId() == paymentDto.SubmittedByPersonId); }

<input type="checkbox" @(canUpdatePaymentStatus != true ? "title=\"Submitter can not approve\"" : string.Empty) />
```

What I'm trying to achieve is if canUpdatePaymentStatus is false set the title attribute to "Submitter can not approve".

Hoever this is not working the markup generated is:

```
<input type="checkbox" title=""Submitter" can="" not="" approve&quot;>
```

so on hover "Submitter is shown.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get the full sentence to appear?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use inline.  try taking title out of the conditional

```
<input type="checkbox" title="@(canUpdatePaymentStatus != true ? "Submitter can not approve" : string.Empty)" />
```

Comment: I also like to use inline but the code in the question suggests the OP doesn't want the ``title`` attribute at all in one of the cases. I'm not sure if that is relevant but if it is, it means you can't use the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

This is more verbose but should work:

```
@{
    var canUpdatePaymentStatus = !(User.GetId() == paymentDto.SubmittedByPersonId);
}
@if (!canUpdatePaymentStatus) {
    <input type="checkbox" title="Submitter can not approve" />
} else {
    <input type="checkbox" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this neatly with an extension method:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourProjectName.Helpers
{
    public static class CheckboxExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxPaymentStatus(this HtmlHelper helper,
            string name, bool canUpdatePaymentStatus)
        {
            if (!canUpdatePaymentStatus)
                return helper.CheckBox(name, new { title = Status });

            return helper.CheckBox(name);
        }

        private static string Status = "Submitter can not approve";
    }
}
```

To make the helper available to your view, you'd need to modify your `~/Views/Web.config` (make sure it's that one and not the one in the root folder of your project) to add the namespace.  In the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` tag you'll find a list of namespaces.  You want to add the helper one to that.  So it might look something like this:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="YourProjectName.Helpers" />
</namespaces>
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxPaymentStatus("PaymentStatus",
    !(User.GetId() == paymentDto.SubmittedByPersonId))
```

You could even modify the helper to take a message as a parameter if you wanted, for extra flexibility.

However, what would be better is to add a `bool` property to your view model called `CanUpdatePaymentStatus` and set that in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    YourPaymentViewModel model = // ...
    model.CanUpdatePaymentStatus = !(User.GetId() == model.SubmittedByPersonId);

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in the view you can simplify things to:

```
@Html.CheckBoxPaymentStatus("PaymentStatus", @Model.CanUpdatePaymentStatus)
```